# Add constraints to side by side four buttons

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add constraints to side by side four buttons. I've tried many methods on Stackoverflow and different sites, but the result is always like the picture. No problem with screens like the iPhone 11 Pro Max. Problems occur on small screens like iPhone 8.

This is xcode design screenshot (iPhone 11 Pro Max)

[image: Simulator]

This is iPhone 8 screenshot

[image: iPhone]

I selected them all and gave the top, right, left, height, equal width, equal height constraints.

[image: Not stackview]

I selected all of them and added top, right, left and height constraints. When I add Stackview, the third row gets corrupted.

[image: Stackview]

Comment: Please show the constraints you are setting.  Have you considered using a stack view?

Comment: Yes, I used the stack view. I added my settings to my question. @Paulw11

Comment: One of your dialogs shows "add 19 constraints".  You should have nowhere near that many constraints. You simply need to constrain the leading/trailing top OR bottom and height of the stack view and probably contrain each button with a 1:1 aspect ratio

Comment: Thank you, i will try @Paulw11